# C++ unspecified future_errc value when packaged_task is wrapped in a thread, code 4

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, packaged-task

As the code below shows, I am trying to implement my own thread class by passing in a packaged_task. I then wait on the future from this packaged_task. I expect this code to wait 4 seconds and then I can get 0xcdcdcdcd from the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

class mythread {
public:
    thread internal_thread;
    template <typename _Fn> mythread(_Fn f) {
        internal_thread = thread([&f] {
            try {
                f();
            }
            catch (std::exception& e) {
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(4));
                std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        });
    }
};

int work() {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    return 0xcdcdcdcd;
}

int main() {
    packaged_task<int()> task(work);
    future<int> ftr = task.get_future();
    mythread thrd(move(task));

    ftr.wait();
    cout << "Got it!!" << endl;
    try {
        cout << ftr.get() << endl;
    }
    catch (future_error &e) {
        std::cout << "outer " << e.code() << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    cout << "Ended" << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

But the wait seems to terminate this task immediately. By compiling executing this code, it immediately prints out

```
Got it!!
outer future:4unspecified future_errc value

Ended
```

The environment is OS X 10.11.1,

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

The compiling command is

```
g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
```

I'm not sure if it reproduces on other platforms.

Thanks in advance.

## Edit

Solved: It is because the constructor of `mythread` now takes control of the life time of `f` moved in, whose reference is used by the thread. But the constructor returns immediately after creating the thread, thus destroying every local variables, including `f`, while the thread is still holding that destroyed local variable.

The corrected code is

```
class mythread {
public:
    thread internal_thread;
    template <typename _Fn> mythread(_Fn f) {
        internal_thread = thread([] (_Fn f) {
            try {
                f();
            }
            catch (std::exception& e) {
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(4));
                std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }, move(f));
    }
};
```

Where the control of `f` is further moved into the thread.

Comment: I think it is because when you call `mythread thrd(move(task));` the shared state from `task` is moved away, `task` no longer has any shared state, and `ftr` - which shares the same state as `task` - no longer has any shared state so there's nothing to wait on.  Call `ftr.valid()` after the move and see what you get.